# Mass automated geotagging of backlog of photos

Tags: batch, geotagging, automation

I frequently record tracklogs with my phone, but have been less diligent about tagging photos with the result.  This is easy to do for an individual track (well, notwithstanding tracks representing e.g. several years of location history - I tried that and LR didn't much like it), but laborious to process a large backlog.  In my case, my backlog largely results from laziness, but this may also apply to people who do a lot of travelling and don't always have the opportunity to apply these processes as they go.

There seem to be many tools (and questions here related to) automated tagging of photos to an existing track log, but none I have seen where this automation is designed to scale to a few hundred tracklogs and many thousands of photos without a lot of user intervention.

As it stands, using Lightroom, for example, the process seems to involve a lot of manual steps for each individual track, navigating back and forth between Map and Library modules to select the right photos... most comments I've found describe this feature in rather more generous terms than I am tempted to use myself.  I'm aware that there are other tools that will do a similar job, but I've not found exactly what I'm looking for.

It should be possible to point a program (which could be a Lightroom plugin for instance) at *all* of my tracklogs and photos, and have it tag any photos taken at times for which tracks exist, without needing any intervention.  As long as the set of tracks and photos are both from a single user with the camera(s) and logging device in the same place, I don't see any major reason why this wouldn't be straightforward to implement.  In more complex cases where tracks and/or photos might not correspond one to one, design of UI would be more challenging (needing for example options to exclude photos taken with a particular camera from the process), but this seems unnecessary for a great many users.

I suppose there's also potential for 'jet-lag', with photos taken shortly after moving to a different timezone being potentially ambiguous.

I can appreciate that there are also liable to be discrepancies resulting from plain old incorrect timestamps (resulting from user error like forgetting to adjust for DST), so it would be desirable to have a GUI with which one could interactively review the tags before applying them... devil is always in the details, but essentially the information is there and the computer should be able to do this job trivially.  If I don't find something that does what I want, I'll probably try to write a script that attempts to do it completely automatically with no GUI whatsoever, or a Lightroom plugin or simple app with some GUI.

Obviously I'd rather not have to reinvent the wheel, though.

Comment: p.s. happy to use any operating system for this (within reason obviously), but more convenient if it's OS-X.

Comment: p.p.s. I seem to remember having a utility for Windows a few years ago that would at least allow loading multiple tracks... I see that http://www.geosetter.de/en does... maybe that was it. That looks like the most promising thing I've seen today, anyway. Will have to boot into Windows to check.

Comment: It should be reasonably easy to merge all the tracks into a single file - does this work or is the file then too large to handle?

Comment: File is too large, I alluded to this in the question, but thanks for the comment. Could be worth experimenting to see how large it will manage.

Comment: You might be able to merge the tracks and then apply some simplification algorithms to the track to bring it under a suitable size. Most tracks contain far too much detail, and if you can cope with a little error in location it should be possible to make the tracks pretty simple.

Comment: That's worth a try; I've a feeling the Google location history export I tried before was already pretty lo-fi, and that was already (much?) too big for LR. So I don't think LR will ever manage the whole job in one go unless the data is massively degraded. The result of taking an overly detailed sample and simplifying it with the right algorithm should probably retain most of the detail though... it'd likely become a case of balancing detail and the number of jobs... I still think it's ridiculous that any of this should be necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What free software exists for geotagging photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14779/what-free-software-exists-for-geotagging-photos)

Comment: I don't see "mass automated" being addressed there, or in any of the many other similar questions?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke judging from the screenshot of the app mentioned in the answer there, it has an input field for a singular gpx file, so almost certainly not useful.  It might be that it would manage with a huge file as discussed above, but I'd certainly argue this is not a duplicate question either way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about producing photographs, it is about data processing in a context that is only peripheral to photography. This is probably more suitable to one of the programming sites here at SE that deal with managing databases.

Comment: FWIW I'm fairly sure I'd know how to program it, probably without needing to ask any SE questions - I'd rather know if there is something that will already do what I want though.  The tool would need to be fairly photography specific, and would IMO be useful to anyone who went on a longish holiday without a computer and wanted to _efficiently_ geotag their files at the end. I can't in all honesty see where else would be more appropriate to ask, or why this question should be off topic while other similar questions are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeffrey Friedl has written a Lightroom plugin which goes a long way to addressing the concerns addressed in this question.

http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/gps

It appears to be sensibly designed and well maintained, and is offered on a very reasonable donation-ware basis with a generous trial period. Indeed, I had used this plugin in the past, before Lightroom (or at least, the version I was using) had any geocoding support - for some reason I'd vaguely assumed that the LR functionality had rendered it mostly redundant to me, but this is not the case.

The way it handles timezones means that it is necessary to manually do separate batches for data that belongs to different timezones, as this is specified by the user at the time of applying the action.  While this does mean that it requires somewhat more manual intervention than I'd hoped for, it reduces it to a manageable level while dealing simply with potential ambiguities that would arise otherwise.